# Navbar not updating upon pressing the logout button, only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use useContext as a global state manager. The user logout does indeed work but the information on the Navbar does not reflect this change until I hit refresh. Why it's not updating the Navbar in particular is beyond me as pressing the log-out button correctly routes the user back to the log-in page but does not update the navbar until the user refreshes. Basically, what is needed is for the navbar's user info to be updated as soon as logout as hit, not when the user refreshes or goes to another page.

Below is my relevant code for this.

```
const Logout = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { user } = useContext(ContextHolder);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onLogoutSuccess = () => {
            _logger('Logged out successfully.');
            toast('You have been logged out');
            navigate('/login');
        };
        const onLogoutError = (message) => {
            _logger('Logout failed:', user.email + ' ' + message);
            navigate('/');
        };

        userService.logout().then(onLogoutSuccess).catch(onLogoutError);
    }, []);

    return <>Logging out ...</>;
};

export default Logout;
```

```
const defaultUser = {
    id: 0,
    roles: [],
    email: '',
    isLoggedIn: false,
};

const ContextHolder = React.createContext({
    user: defaultUser,
});

export default ContextHolder;
```

```
const NavBar = () => {
    const { user } = useContext(ContextHolder);


    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="py-lg-3 navbar" variant="light">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/" className="me-lg-5">
                    <img src={logo} alt="" className="logo-dark" height="50px" />
                </Navbar.Brand>

                <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <i className="mdi mdi-menu"></i>
                </Navbar.Toggle>
                <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                    <Nav as="ul" className="me-auto align-items-center">
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <AiOutlineLink /> <Nav.Link href="/listings">View Listings</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <MdOutlineQuestionAnswer /> <Nav.Link href="/faq">FAQs</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <BsFillPeopleFill /> <Nav.Link href="/blogs">Blogs</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <AiFillPhone /> <Nav.Link href="/contactus">Contact</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <RiProfileLine /> <Nav.Link href="/profile">Profile</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <BiMap /> <Nav.Link href="/location">Location</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <GoVerified /> <Nav.Link href="/location/verification">Location Verification</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light text-nowrap border-0 text-center">
                            <TbInfoCircle /> <Nav.Link href="/AboutUs">About Us</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0 text-center">
                            <FaCogs /> <Nav.Link href="/externallinks">External Links</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                        <Nav.Item className="mx-lg-1 btn btn-outline-light border-0">
                            <GoChecklist /> <Nav.Link href="/venues">Venues</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav.Item>
                    </Nav>

                    <Nav className="ms-auto align-items-center">
                        {user.isLoggedIn ? (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <Nav.Item className="me-0 text-center">
                                    <span className="text-dark fw-bold"> Welcome back, {user.email}!</span>
                                </Nav.Item>
                                <Nav.Item>
                                    <Link
                                        to="/logout"
                                        className="mx-3 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark d-none d-lg-inline-flex mt-1"
                                        style={{ width: '80px' }}>
                                        Log Out
                                    </Link>
                                </Nav.Item>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ) : (
                            <Nav.Item className="me-0">
                                <Nav.Link href="/login" target="_self" className="d-lg-none">
                                    Log In
                                </Nav.Link>
                                <Link
                                    to="/login"
                                    target="_self"
                                    className="mx-3 btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark d-none d-lg-inline-flex">
                                    Log In
                                </Link>
                            </Nav.Item>
                        )}
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
            </div>
        </Navbar>
    );
};

NavBar.propTypes = {
    currentUser: PropTypes.shape({
        id: PropTypes.number,
        roles: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
        email: PropTypes.string,
        isLoggedIn: PropTypes.bool,
    }),
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: What is `userService.logout()` doing? It should be setting the user in the context (probably to the default user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for all the related components to know the variable "user" has changed at any given moment because "user" is not a state. Right now, react renders your components through a 'static' and to its knowledge 'never changing variable' which explains why the view renders correctly only  AFTER refreshing. you should create a state like so

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(defaultUser);
```

Also, you should wrap your code with a context provider and add the "user" state inside the "value" prop, also pass the "setUser" function so you could set the user at any given moment from your application. in your case:

```
<ContextHolder.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
    ...
</ContextHolder.Provider>
```

All in all your code should look something like this:

```
const defaultUser = { ... };

function App () {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(defaultUser);

    return (
        <ContextHolder.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            <NavBar />
            <Logout />
            ...etc..
        </ContextHolder.Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: This made it work beautifully. Thank you very much, I was struggling all weekend with this and I feel foolish for not getting it sooner.

Comment: @DaleK I'm sorry but no, I am not.